# Why does not work ng-class in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I have `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="num in arr" ng-class="selected(num.id) ? 'active' : ''">
   <span>{{num.name}}</span>
</div>
```

Also method `selected()` that checkes if element is active:

```
$scope.selected = function(num){
    angular.forEach($scope.categorySelect, function (value, key) {
        if(value.id == num){
            // Here works console.log()
            return ($scope.categorySelect[key].checked == true) ? false : true;
        }
    })
}
```

But for me it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntax for the `ng-class` should be like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="num in arr" ng-class="{ 'active': selected(num.id) }">
```

Also your `$scope.selected()` doesn't return anything. You are returning a boolean in your anonymous function which breaks the `forEach`.

Change your function like this

```
$scope.selected = function (num) {
    var isSelected = false;

    angular.forEach($scope.categorySelect, function (value, key) {
        if(value.id == num){
            isSelected = $scope.categorySelect[key].checked;
            return;
        }
    });

    return isSelected;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
<div ng-repeat="num in arr" ng-class="{'active': selected(num.id) }">
   <span>{{num.name}}</span>
</div>
```

See [ngClass Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

Answer (score 0):

You ng-class syntax is wrong :

```
ng-class="{'active' : selected(num.id)}"
```